# MyBatis JNDI with JBoss not closing connections

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, connection-pooling, mybatis

I actually can't understand why this is happening. I'm running some enterprise programs, from EJB to a Web-App. My EJB uses `MyBatis` with my Postgres DB, while is deployed, with my web-app, on an instance of `JBoss-AS 7`. actually JBoss crashes because connections exceeds from the pool that I've configured on my JNDI datasource in the `standalone.xml`.

My datasource is configured like this in the `standalone.xml`:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDBName" pool-name="MyDBName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
     <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/My_DB</connection-url>
     <driver>postgresql-driver</driver>
     <pool>
         <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
         <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
         <prefill>true</prefill>
     </pool>
     <security>
         <user-name>username</user-name>
         <password>password</password>
     </security>
</datasource>
```

I've configured my datasource like this into the mybatis-config.xml:

```
<transactionManager type="MANAGED">
    <property name="closeConnection" value="false"/>
</transactionManager>
<dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:jboss/datasources/MyDBName"/>
</dataSource>
```

I've also tried to manually close the SQLSession in my DAO every time I use it, but nothing happened.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I would download source jars of relevant libraries, create a project having these libraries as dependencies, enable remote debugging in jBoss7 and remote debug what's going on within jBoss and myBatis with the connections. Luckily, all software libraries are open sourced. Not bug free but at least we can see what's inside.

Comment: So your suggestion is to track both jboss and mybatis and see who is going "mad"?

Comment: I've solved myself several issues using remote debugging. The code is not that hard to understand, especially if there's a big pain caused by it :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `session.close()` when using the `MANAGED` type it does not send a connection.close(). So you create your own class that implements `org.apache.ibatis.transaction.TransactionFactory` interface. See sample;

```
public class ClosingTransaction implements Transaction {
    private Connection connection;
    public ClosingTransaction(Connection conn){
        connection = conn;
    }
    public void close() throws SQLException {
    // this will call connection.close(), so the container knows
    // to release the connection to the pool
        connection.close();
    }
    public void commit() throws SQLException {
    //nothing, container managed
    }
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
    public void rollback() throws SQLException {
    // nothing, container managed
    }
}

public class ClosingTransactionFactory implements TransactionFactory {
    public Transaction newTransaction(Connection conn, boolean autocommit) {
    return new ClosingTransaction(conn);
    }
    public void setProperties(Properties props) {
    }
}
```

In your mybatis-config.xml;

```
<transactionManager type="com.example.ClosingTransactionFactory"/>
<dataSource type="JNDI">
    <property name="data_source" value="java:jboss/datasources/MyDBName"/>
</dataSource>
```

Comment: I tried setting the closeConnection to true, and then using session.close(). This worked for me...